# Updating mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

Hello need some help....

I am using the codes below and my table isn't updating.

```
$date = array("1001", "1002", "1003");
$sql="select ID from fid;";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Query failed : " . mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
  $test_id = $row[0];           
  foreach ($date as $datex){
    $sql2="UPDATE tbl1 SET date1=(SELECT date1n FROM dat".$datex." WHERE ID=".$test_id.")";                     
    mysql_query($sql2);
```

But when I change the `dat".$datex."` to `dat1001` (which is a real table name) and the `".$test_id."` to `989` (which is a real ID num), it is updating.. I'm not sure why it's not updating when i use the declared variables. :(

Comment: make sure the fid table is correctly populated. Potentially print the sql2 to match the sql statements: echo $sql2;

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using php.
Take a look at this:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE layout SET `set` = '$set' ...
```

See how the " are before '. you need to just surround variables with right quotation marks.

Check out this page : [LINK](http://tycoontalk.freelancer.com/the-database-forum/61653-php-variable-in-sql-update-table.html)

Comment: Thank you for all the help. I just removed some of the punctuation marks and it seems that it's updating with no value. I tried to echo the $sql2, and I can see that the values are there but on the DB I can't see it. I mean, it's just blank.